# Touch event based on random number generated on object

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch

```
int rand=((arc4random()%4)+1);
```

how would you go about making a `touch event` due to the numbers generated from `int rand`.

Example if the numbers generated are `1,2,2,3,4` and you have `4 buttons` with a tag `1,2,3,4`.

how would you make an event where you have to touch an object in order of the number generated by the int `rand` method?

Answer (score 0):

Make 4 buttons give oneaction

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

{

```
rand=((arc4random()%4)+1);
```

}

-(IBAction)myMethod
    {

```
switch (rand)
{

case 1:
//Do for first button tag
break;

case 2:
//Do for second button tag
break;

case 3:
//Do for third button tag
break;

case 4:
//Do for fourth button tag
break;


default:
break;
}

}
```